# How can I display the build time in my Android application?

Tags: android

When I develop my application and correct it once and again, I would like to see if the one running now is the last I built. Hence, I would like to add a field, say a TextView, that will display the build time-of-day (e.g., 19:26).

How can I take the build time and embed it in activity_main.xml?
BTW - build version, a counter that progresses with every build, is also good. Anything that will indicate the last build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're building with Gradle, you can add a `BuildConfig` field with the desired information in your `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        def buildTime = new Date()
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}\""
        ... other stuff ...
    }
    ...other stuff ...
}
```

And then in your Kotlin/Java code:

```
myTextView.text = BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME
```

---

Another alternative is to replace the `buildConfigField` line in the above example with:

```
resValue "string", "build_time", "${buildTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')}"
```

Which creates a string resource that you can use in your layout XML file, e.g.:

```
android:text="@string/build_time"
```

Comment: I had to add the following line to file `app/build.gradle` to make this working: `android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true`